# Angular http.get error with {{responseType: 'text}}

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Whenever i try to use {{requestType: 'text'}} in my http.get(url) call I get an error that I am unable to diff and only arrays and iterables are allowed; however, I am taking my object and transforming it into an array. I need some assistance understanding my error and how to fix my situation

When I remove the RequestType the array comes through no issues and displays on my front end.

```
----service-----

 getAll(){
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      /* other options here */
      responseType: 'text'
    }
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url, requestOptions);
} 

---component .ts----- 

notificationsFass: any[];

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private metaService: Meta, private notificationService: NotificationsFassService) {
    this.notificationsFass = [];
}


ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.getAll()
      .subscribe(notificationsFass => {
        this.notificationsFass = notificationsFass;
      }
        );
}

---html---

<div *ngFor="let m of notificationsFass">

---error----
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"incidentNumber":700,"createdByName":"FASS Notification","createdDate":"2019-03-27T09:18:15.000+0000"}]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Comment: What is the actual content-type being sent from the server? If the content-type is `application/json` there would be no reason to use `responseType: 'text'`. The "data" displayed in the error looks to be JSON, so you can just use the default `responseType` so that HttpClient parses the received JSON for use in your template. What is the reason you are wanting to use `responseType: 'text'`?

Comment: *however, I am taking my object and transforming it into an array.*: where? The posted code doesn't do that anywhere. You're trying to iterate through a string.

Comment: It is application/json ; however, I am getting httpResponse errors from my server when it can't render JSON from what I've read that if I can have the httpResponse text I may get rid of those errors

Comment: JB nizet, in my ngOnInit() am I not taking the json object and then assigning it to the notificationFass array in my component? excuse my ignorance

Comment: No, you are taking your text response from the server (a string) and overwriting the empty array that is `notificationFass`.

Comment: Right, `*ngFor` can only render objects of a specific format such as an array of objects. Definitely do not use `responseType: 'text'` if your content-type is `application/json`. It will not be parsed and will simply be a string that under no circumstances could be used by structural directives such as `*ngFor`. You should probably share the logic you had taking the response prior to the `text` `responseType` change and turning it into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the json in the error message you need to do the following:

- Define an interface, I used the name `INotification`. This will define the members available on the deserialized json response.
- Strongly type the method return types and also supply the generic type argument in `http.get<T>`. When `http.get` is called it will try to deserialize the json response from the server to an object graph. By defining `INotification[]` as the returned type further callers, like from a component, can now safely call members on the return type like `find` or other Array.prototype members as well as access the defined members on instances in the array.

`responseType: 'text'` is only necessary when you are not emitting a response from the server *or* when the response is text and not json. The former can happen with `post` or `put` or `delete` calls where the server might only send a status and no message body in the response.

Here is your service code rewritten based on the feedback above.

**notificationsFassService.ts**

```
export interface INotification {
    incidentNumber: number;
    createdByName: string;
    createdDate: string;
}

export class NotificationsFassService {
    constructor (private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll():Observable<INotification[]> {
        return this.http.get<INotification[]>(this.url);
    } 
}
```

**notificationsFassComponent.ts**

```
export class NotificationsFassComponent implements OnInit {
    notificationsFass: INotification[];

    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private metaService: Meta, private notificationService: NotificationsFassService) {
        this.notificationsFass = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.notificationService.getAll()
          .subscribe(notificationsFass => {
             this.notificationsFass = notificationsFass;
          });
    }
}
```